# How to use HTTP2 in YII application?

Tags: php, yii, amazon-ec2

Already I am having YII(1.1.14) application which is running in amazon server. So i planned to use HTTP2, So kindly tell me anybody what is procedure to use HTTP2 in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try h2o and curl. h2o supports php-fpm since v 1.3. Here is example of h2o.conf.

```
file.custom-handler:
  extension: .php
  fastcgi.connect:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 9000
    type: tcp
listen:
  port: 8080
  ssl:
    certificate-file: /path/to/server.crt
    key-file: /path/to/server.key
hosts:
  "127.0.0.1.xip.io:8080":
    paths:
      /:
        file.dir: /path/to/public_html
```

You can create http2 requests with libcurl built with nghttp2. All you have to do is use `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0`.

```
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
    define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 + 1);
}

$url = 'https://http2bin.org/get';

$opts = [
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend giving H20 a go. It's been stable so far. Configuration is very clear and easy if you are familiar with YAML or similar.

Here is an article to get you started with Yii, HHVM and HTTP/2: https://www.symfony.fi/entry/serving-php-on-http-2-with-h2o-and-hhvm-symfony-wordpress-drupal